# Connection of database in QGIS with the SSH tunnel port like doing in postgreSQL maestro

Tags: postgresql, server, database-connection, postgis, ssh-tunnel

How to connect the PostgreSQL database in QGIS with the SSH tunnel port like doing in PostgreSQL maestro?

SSH tunnel has different ports and host

the database has different ports and host

Also, Both have different usernames and password

Any idea?

Error:
Server closed the connection unexpectedly before or while passing the request.

Comment: What did you try?  What went wrong?  How does "maestro" do it? The ports and hosts and usernames and passwords are different from *what*?

Comment: I wanna connect from my localhost QGIS with SSH Tunneling.
In QGIS there is nothing like SSH Tunneling.
If I use third party PuTTy or others, connection with SSH Tunneling is form but still the same question how am I supposed to connect with QGIS

Answer (score 0):

After opening a tunnel (with Putty or ssh or whatever), you just point QGIS at it.  Use 'localhost' for the host and (probably) 5432 for the port.  You could have picked a different port if you wanted to when you set up the tunnel, so use whatever that was.  QGIS won't *know* it is using a tunnel.

Comment: It did not work. Maybe I am making some mistakes. Could you please share some screenshots?

Comment: You want a screenshot of a lack of an error message?

Comment: the suggestion you have given, I have followed it, unfortunately it did not work.